# Alias instead of new variable for sugar syntax

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, syntactic-sugar

Consider `char firstLetter=word[0];`, where you do not do anything with `firstLetter` besides use it as sugar for readability. Is there something other than `#define` that can just make an inline "alias" instead of allocating new memory? I realize a script can be written but if something already exists...

Comment: C++ or C (or both)? The answer (and its convenience) varies between the two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question really *is* about C++, you can always create an alias for the object:

```
char& firstLetter=word[0];
```

This will make `firstLetter` and alias for `word[0]` (assuming `word` is an array, and not a pointer that is changed later).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks, Bo. For anyone reading this, I also found out about constexpr in C++11 for similar but not identical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There's no memory allocation that goes on here; the value of `word[0]` may be copied into a register or onto the stack, but it's up to the compiler whether it needs to do even this.

Note that an "inline alias" would lead to far worse code being generated; the expression `word[n]` implies some computation which, if you used some kind of substitution, would be repeated multiple times.

Comment: Well, unless the compiler does common sub-expression elimination and computes the address once. Which it may very well do (save for nasty things like `volatile`). This is no question of efficiency.